# Importing namespaced files in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following files:

/lib/stripe/stripe_invoice.rb

```
class StripeInvoice
...
end
```

Now in my controller I am trying to use it:

```
def index

      si = StripeInvoice.new(...)

end
```

I get an error for uninitialized constant StripInvoice.

If I add:

```
require 'lib/stripe_invoice'
```

I get the error:

```
cannot load such file -- lib/stripe_invoice
```

What is the correct way to import my class file so I can use it in my controller?

Also, how can I create a namespace for my class StripeInvoice and how would that change the way I import it?

Comment: `require 'lib/stripe_invoice'` is missing `/stripe/`. Should be `require 'lib/stripe/stripe_invoice'`

Answer (score 1):

> cannot load such file -- lib/stripe_invoice

You don't have `stripe_invoice.rb` in `lib` but `lib/stripe`

Replace:

```
require 'lib/stripe_invoice'
```

with

```
require 'lib/stripe/stripe_invoice'
```